# Stackoverflow doesn't remember me, need to login after every browser restart

Tags: support, login, firefox, cookies

Hey,

I have been having this problem for some time, but could not find a solution.

Whenever i restart my Browser (Firefox 3.5.6) and go to stackoverflow.com (or superuser or meta) i have to login with my OpenID again, which is very annoying.

Cookies are enabled.

I hope someone can help.

Regards 
Nick

Answer (score 3):

Ok i just found the solution myself.

It appears there is a hidden function in the Firefox settings like "delete cookies on exit".
(I dont know exactly because my Firefox speaks german ;) ) 
Anyway i deactivated it and now it works.... silly me.

Regards

Comment: yes so don't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce in another web browser? Does it happen in Firefox safe mode?

Sounds like a cookie problem specific to Firefox on that machine..

Comment: with Konqueror it works fine.
It happens in Firefox safe mode too...